# Please check if there is anything wrong with this proof.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

**Please check the following proof.**

Consider the function $f[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$

**Theorem :**

$f[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous

$\implies$

$\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \ \text{partition of}\ [a,b]$ $\ni (\forall\ \text{subinterval}) \ (\text{span } f < \epsilon)$

**Proof:**

$f[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous

$\implies$ $f$ is continuous at $a$

$\implies$ $\forall\ \epsilon>0$, $\left(\exists\ \delta \right) \left(-\delta < a-x < \delta\ \Rightarrow \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} < f(a)-f(x) < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}\right)$

$\implies \left(\exists\ \delta_1\right) \left(-\delta_1 < a-x < \delta_1\ \Rightarrow -\dfrac{\epsilon_0}{2} < f(a)-f(x) < \dfrac{\epsilon_0}{2}\right)$

$\implies \left(\exists\ \delta_1\right) \left(x \in (a-\delta_1,a+\delta_1) \Rightarrow -\dfrac{\epsilon_0}{2} < f(a)-f(x) < \dfrac{\epsilon_0}{2}\right)$

$\implies$ $\left( -\dfrac{\epsilon_0}{2} < f(a)-f(x_{S1}) < \dfrac{\epsilon_0}{2} \right)   \land    \left(  -\dfrac{\epsilon_0}{2} < f(x_{B1})-f(a) < \dfrac{\epsilon_0}{2}  \right)$

$\implies$ $\left( 0 < f(a)-f(x_{S1}) < \dfrac{\epsilon_0}{2} \right)   \land    \left(  0 < f(x_{B1})-f(a) < \dfrac{\epsilon_0}{2}  \right)$

$\implies$ $0 < f(x_{B1})-f(x_{S1}) < \epsilon_0$

$\implies$ span $f$ in $ (a-\delta_1,a+\delta 1 < \epsilon_0$

$\implies$ span $f$ in $ (a,a+\delta_1)=$ span $f$ in $ (a,a_1) < \epsilon_0$

Similarly:

span $f$ in $ (a_0,a_1) < \epsilon_0$

span $f$ in $ (a_1,a_2) < \epsilon_0$

span $f$ in $ (a_2,a_3) < \epsilon_0$

.....

span $f$ in $ (a_{(i-1)} ,a_i) < \epsilon_0$

span $f$ in $ (a_i,a_{(i+1)} ) < \epsilon_0$

where:

$a_i \in [a,b]$

$a_{(i+1)} \notin [a,b]$

Thus we see for partition $P_{[a,b]}=\{a=a_0, a_1, a_2,...,a_i, b \}$

$(\forall\ \text{subinterval}) \ (\text{span } f < \epsilon_0)$

Analogously $\forall\ \epsilon > 0$, we can make a partition of $[a,b] \ni (\forall\ \text{subinterval}) \ (\text{span } f < \epsilon)$

**Please tell whether there are any mistakes in the above proof.**

Comment: Please consider using a more meaningful title for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with your proof. Why can you state that $b$ will be reached in a finite number of steps? "The $\delta_i$ may become smaller and smaller".

For example the map

$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
f : & [0,1) & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R \\
    & x & \longmapsto & \frac{1}{1-x}
\end{array}$$

is continuous but you won't be able to reach $1$ in a finite number of steps.

The compactness of $[a,b]$ has to come into play somewhere in proof of your theorem.

Comment: Can the compacity of $[a,b]$ be included in the proof with a small modification of the proof?

Comment: @lorilori I do not think that any small modification will help. You've go to start, I think, using continuity at every point of $[a,b]$ and then using compactness to extract a finite set of intervals covering $[a,b]$ on which you have control of how much $f$ varies.

Comment: Can I use the theorem "continuous function on a closed and bounded interval is uniformly continuous" in the proof? Doesn't everything is OK then?